# Do log4j or Logback support memory mapped files?

Tags: java, log4j, real-time, slf4j, logback

Does any of these logging libraries support memory mapped files? If not, is there a Java logging library that supports it?

UPDATES:

@paulsm4 I am talking about `java.nio.MappedByteBuffer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "memory mapped files", or what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

But one approach might be to write your logs to a RAM disk.  For example:

http://www.ubuntuka.com/ubuntu-ramdisk-ramdrive-easy-way/

Comment: I am talking about java.nio.MappedByteBuffer from Java NIO.

Answer (score 1):

Slf4j is not a logging library.  It is a facade for the real logging library / system that you are using.  As such, the question is moot for slf4j.

Log4j does not provide an `Appender` implementation that is specified as using memory mapped files.  It might do under the hood.  You would need to check the source code.

The same applies for Logback.

---

AFAIK, there is nothing stopping you writing your own appender for Log4j or Logback that used a mapped file.  It would be interesting to see if there are any performance benefits in doing this.  (My guess would be no.  Memory mapping only really makes sense for read and read/write files.  A log file is write-only from the perspective of the application.)

Comment: The performance gain with Memory Mapped Files is close to 5 fold. I measured them myself on Linux and Mac.

Comment: @chrisapotek - did you measure it for writing a log file?  Or for something else?  Please provide the benchmark code that we can validate your result.  (It sounds implausible to me.)

Comment: You are going to have to trust me on this one. The big advantage of memory mapped files is that you don't have to make the system call fileChannel.write for every single message you want to log. You just write to a MappedByteBuffer in memory and the OS is responsible for persisting the data when and how it wants. As a result the gain in performance is huge. If you don't believe me that's fine. :) But thanks for answering about log4j and logback. I am surprised that these two popular libraries do not support memory mapped files

Comment: @chrisapotek - let us know if it actually works.  I've a feeling that there is a big gotcha in your approach.  That would explain why the authors of a log4j and logback haven't implemented it.

Comment: You may want to bring this up on the logback mailing list.  This is where the most new development happens these days.

Answer (score 1):

I've contributed an [appender](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-431) to Log4j 2 that writes to mapped files.